# Pattern Matching htaccess conflict

Tags: .htaccess

I have migrated my site to new software and am trying to ensure that older links are appropriately redirected to the new url's. I thought I had it working until I received the message from Google regarding increasing 404's.

I seem though to be causing a conflict between the new htaccess requirements and my changes to address the old links.

So the new links look like this:

```
http://www.exampledomain.com/search/?q=searchterm
```

And in the htaccess they are picked up like this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
```

The above is working as it should.

The old links can look like either of these:

```
http://www.exampledomain.com/search/searchterm/
or
http://www.exampledomain.com/search/searchterm
```

I had put this in to the htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/$ http://www.exampledomain.com/search.php?q=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

If I don't add the first rule then the new url's just bring up 404's.

If I add second rule the it stops the searchterm being passed and conflicts with the first rule.

Have tried a few things but think there must be an issue with the matching or something else i'm missing.

Any ideas appreciated.

** Added **

So after the first reply I made the change as suggested and it caused a couple of issues but switching the order of the rules has fixed that but has not quite fixed the issue

So now I have this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?$ http://www.exampledomain.com/search.php?q=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
```

The above works for these url's now:

```
http://www.exampledomain.com/search/?q=searchterm
and
http://www.exampledomain.com/search/searchterm
```

But for url's like this:

```
http://www.exampledomain.com/search/searchterm/
```

it results in this with a trailing slash which prevents the search:

http://www.exampledomain.com/search.php?q=drama/

So just need to remove or not have the trailing slash

Comment: Your question is probably more suited to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing a `?` in the rule since the `/` is optional:

`RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

**Update to address trailing slash:**

I'm guessing that the `.*` is consuming the trailing `/` before the next rule. To fix that, we need to exclude it from the match:

`RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

**Update to address added case where parameter appears after slash:**

I'm not sure if you mean literally `/search/q=searchstr` or `/search/?q=searchstr` so I will attempt to address both cases.

If it's the latter, which is a true query string, place this rule above the first using `QSA` in order to pass the query string along to the new URL:

`RewriteRule ^search/$ search.php [R=301,NC,QSA,L]`

To address the first variation (without the `?` query string), you will need to place this rule above the first, which literally looks for the `q=`:

`RewriteRule ^search/q=(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

And since I get the feeling you'll update this question again to ask about what happens if there is a trailing slash, I'll go ahead and modify that rule to handle this case as well:

`RewriteRule ^search/q=([^/]*)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

If these rules still don't solve every case for you, then you're dealing with some really bad code from your previous URL and I feel very sorry for you. :P

Comment: Hi thanks for that - it nearly worked and has got another url working but still has an issue have added the results to the question above but basically it leaves a trailing slash now

Comment: Thanks for the update and your time - that gets the three main url's working brilliant. It does now stop one type where the url is like this /search/q=searchterm as it now fails to pass over the searchterm. As the main ones are working now though I might just change the coding on this one as i'm not sure it can be resolved without conflicting with the others.

Comment: Well all I can say is.... Many Thanks!! All working perfectly now and I appreciate your patience and time updating the answers. My apologies for missing off the ? in the previous reply and causing you extra work. It has saved me loosing a good few thousand url's in Google and this was the one with the most variants.

Comment: Ah yes, fixing all the bad links Google has indexed. I know the feeling well. Glad it's working for you now!